# Replacing dots with space

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to replace dots  with space and it is working, but it is also replacing values that has commas.

Example
1.506,45
is transformed to
1 506,45

but
1,506,45
is transformed to
1 506,45

and it is ruining the values.
Any ideas how to replace ONLY dots and not commas?

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Select

Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply use the `=SUBSTITUTE()` formula:

On a nearby cell:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, ". ", " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

try with =Substitute(col,oldtxt,newtxt)